# Does lift have validation for urls?

Tags: scala, lift

I want my users to be able to enter their webpage url when signing up.
Does lift have any built in support for url format validation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, no, but you can create a simple validation rule:

```
import java.net.{ URL, URISyntaxException };
import scala.util.Try

def isValidUrl(url: String): Boolean = {
  Try { val link = new URL(url); true } getOrElse false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your users have an HTML5 browser, you can use the [`SHtml.url`](http://liftweb.net/api/25/api/#net.liftweb.http.SHtml) function to generate an input that is validated client-side. This relies on the HTML `type="url"` attribute for an input and so is only supported in more modern browsers.

There is no server-side validation baked into Lift, but you can use any number of third party ones like [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/validator/UrlValidator.html) or as @flavian mentioned, you can write your own.